# Where should I do mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php

I have a quick question about mysql_real_escape_string. Where should I use it?

I have a *.php file with form that is redirecting it to itself, but that file is using another file that has class in it with function Add(params);

So should I escape strings when they are submitted?

```
$catName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['edtCatAddName']);
```

Or should I escape strings in my class?

```
$catName = mysql_real_escape_string($catName);
```

Or perhaps both these situations are wrong and I need to do something else? I've tried to escape just my query like this

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string("INSERT INTO cat (catName, catDescr, catImg, catSubLevel, catSubID) VALUES ('$catName', '$catDescr', '$catImgURL', $catSubLevel, $catSubID)");
```

But it's not too good because this way my query won't go since catName and some other variables are string type and I need to add ' before and after them and these chars are escaped.

Any advice? I'm very new to this...

So if I use PDO then all I have to do is

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("my raw, not escaped query");  
$STH->execute();
```

and I can feel secure?

Comment: Re: 'So if I use PDO then all I have to do is `$STH...` and I can feel secure?' - now I want to -1 all the guys who advised you to use PDO without providing valid examples. (For the record- no, you can't feel secure. That's perfect example of misused prepared statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nowhere, you should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) prepared statements instead to protect you against SQL-injections.

Answer (score 1):

**When to use mysql_real_escape_string()**

Actually `mysql_real_escape_string()` is used while sanitize a input from a user. So you should (at least) use it everywhere a user can input anything that goes into a query. It is also very suggested to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

**What Prepared Statements are**

Basically they are sql queries that are very safe.
Let's make an example.

```
SELECT UserName FROM user WHERE UserUID = X
```

Is a simple query. Let's say that the `X` is a variable that come from a `$_GET` input. Some users could add to X everything. Even a `1;` and then start a new query. This technique is called [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Now with `mysql_real_escape_string()` you solve part of this problem, and it's quite safe. But Prepared statements tell the server that

```
SELECT UserName FROM user WHERE UserUID =
```

Is something like a static part, and then that `X` is a variable. In this way the server is kinda *prepared* to execute such a query, and nothing else, considering any input in `X` like an input. In this way you have not to worry about user inputs at all.

Comment: +1 for explaining what prepared statements really are. Note that MySQLi also supports prepared statement (although the API is pretty lousy if you don't wrap it in some utility classes). Also prepared statements can not (or are difficult to) be used in each and every case, and can also be misused and not provide any security benefits at all. For more details see Bill Karwin's excellent 'SQL Antipatterns` presentation.

Comment: Oh didn't know that. I remembered i read (somewhere, probably here) that PDO is easy to use everywhere and gave benefits in any case. I'm using it in my project and it seems to solve all my needs. Could you please provide an example on how PDO should not give benefits at all?

Comment: I'm talking about prepared statements (whether in PDO or in MySQLi or anywhere really), not about PDO. See: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2670985/SQL-Antipatterns - go to slide 163, and pay special attention to slides 181 and 182. In general however, prepared statements are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
$catName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['catName']);
```

or use `mysql_real_escape_string()` directly in your query.

For values which are expected to be a number (integer, float) - you can either use `intval($var)` for integers or `floatval($var)` for floats.

BUT:
never use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the entire query - that's simply wrong ;-)

EDIT:
I forgot to mention: the best is to use `PDO`(PHP Data Objects) -> http://de.php.net/PDO

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Use parameters in queries using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Mysqli doesn't really solve anything. He will have to escape its input anyway.